# I want to create javascript string so that when it is passed inside a div tag it shows as a list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to display a string containing a list of items in a specific format inside a `div` tag using JavaScript. The string contains several items that I want to display as a bulleted list. Here's the example string:

```js
const items = "These are the items:\n1. apple\n2. mango";
```

I want to format the string so that it appears as follows inside the `div` tag:

```
These are the items:
1. apple
2. mango
```

I am using React and Tailwind CSS, and this question pertains to a React component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the string by the newline character, then map it into multiple paragraph tags

```js
const items = "These are the items:\n1. apple\n2. mango";

// or if you want it t be reactive:
const [items, setItems] = useState("These are the items:\n1. apple\n2. mango");
```

Then in the html:

```html
    <div className="list">
      {items.split('\n').map((el) => (
         <p>{el}</p>
       ))}
    </div>
```

Now the list is displayed correctly, if the items are centered and you want them to be aligned left just put text-align: left; in the list css class

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the map method, by splitting it whenever any '/n' is encountered. Also, you can create an ordered list for this purpose as well.  For instance, find the code below.

```js
import React from 'react';
    
const items = "\n1. apple\n2. mango";

const ListComponent = () => {
    const itemList = items.split('\n').map((item, index) => {
        const trimmedItem = item.replace(/^\d+\.\s/, '');
        if (item.trim()) {
          return <li key={index}>{ trimmedItem}</li>;
        }
        return null;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Here is the list:</p>
            <p>These are the items:</p>
            <ol>{itemList}</ol>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ListComponent;
```

Here the screenshot for the above code when runs
[running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOsNq.png)

Comment: This will end up with duplicate numbers, for example  "1. 1. apple" and "2. 2. mango".

Comment: @icc97, thanks a lot for pointing it out sir, I have rectified it.

Comment: I find the idea of an ordered list much better. You could easily drop the leading number and point with `item.replace(/^\d+\.\s/, '')` so that the automatic numbering of the `<ol><li>...</li>....</ol>` takes over. I would also remove the `<p>Here is the list:</p>` and put the first item of the list in a `<p>` tag and not in the `<li>` items. I vote for your response, which seems the only one wanting to create an ordered list, which is the correct HTML semantic for this question.

Comment: @PatrickJanser yes, I agree, its more semantically correct, however as with my first comment here you end up with duplicate "1. 1.", so you would need regex to replace the `\n[0-9]\. `. The change made here makes this answer now effectively the same as [@JustChris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76487926/327074).

Comment: I have tried updating it as per your suggestions. Thanks for making me and my answer better.
Special thanks to @icc97 for providing me with my first reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

```js
const items = "These are the items:\n1. apple\n2. mango";
document.getElementById("thediv").innerText=items;
```

```html
<div id="thediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = "These are the items:\n1. apple\n2. mango";
console.log(string.split("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your string in order to have a list.
A very simple parse would be :
`items.split('/n')`

and you would receive

`["These are the items:", "1. apple", "2. mango"]`
which is now easy to display